# Is Span(V) defined as the set V or a spanning list of V?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Terminology question that my textbook is not helping with.

I am to prove the following proposition (do not want solutions):

Take finite vector spaces $V, W$

Prove: $V \subset \text{span}(W) \Longrightarrow \text{span}(V) \subset \text{span}(W)$

In this context, does span$(W)$ refer to all elements that can be reached with span$(W)$ (that is, all of $W$), or an arbitrary list from which each $w \in W$ can be constructed by a linear combination? (Or perhaps even the smallest possible spanning list of $W$)

Much thanks.

Comment: It is the smallest subspace containing $V$. Equivalently, the intersection of all subspaces containing $V$. Or the set of all finite linear combinations of $V$. In particular, $V \subset \operatorname{sp} V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually span(W) refers to the vector space spanned by the set W. For example you might take a vector and its span would be a one dimensional subspace. If $W \subset V$ where $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$,  we could write this in symbols as

$$\text{span}(W) = \{ \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i \; | \; \lambda_i \in F, v_i \in W\}$$

In words, it's all finite linear combinations of vectors from $W$. I only used $W$ here because you did, it's more typical for $W$ to be some finite set (not necessarily a vector space), something like $\text{span}(v_1,v_2)$ for the vector space spanned by $v_1,v_2$. Hopefully it's also clear that $\text{span}(W) = W$ if and only if $W$ actually is a vector space.

You haven't said what $B$ is so I can't speak to that.